# Tkinter window different format while executing .py file and with spyder

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

My Tkinter window is appearing different while I am executing the .py file compared to how it is appearing while executing with spyder. I want my window to look like spyder execution on normal .py file execution.

spyder version: 4.1.3
Python version: 3.7.6 (anaconda installation)

GIT hub link (code link) below:
https://github.com/manojbuddha/minesweeper-using-tkinter.git

[.py file execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TW9m.png)
[Spyder execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XYwy.png)

```
for self.row in range(0,self.rows):
        for self.column in range(0,self.columns):
            self.button = Button(self.lower_frame,height=self.BUTTON_HEIGHT, 
                                 width=self.BUTTON_WIDTH,  borderwidth=self.BUTTON_BORDER_WIDTH, 
                                 relief=self.BUTTON_STYLE)
            self.position = [self.row, self.column]        
            self.button.bind("<Button-2>", lambda event,position=self.position: 
                             self.right_click(event,position))
            self.button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event,position=self.position: 
                             self.right_click(event,position))        
            self.button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event,position=self.position: 
                             self.left_click(event,position))   
            self.button.grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)
            self.buttons.append(self.button)  
    self.window.resizable(False,False)
```

Comment: Add your code to the post please

Comment: sorry for that Tim, added the GitHub link, also u can find the attached images related to the Tkinter window

Comment: No one wants to read through your entire project. If I were you, I'd add the *relevant code* to this post

Comment: Should use same font weight when initializing the buttons.  Also add `sticky='nsew'` to `grid()` on the buttons.

Comment: Also it is not necessary to re-create the button when it is clicked.

Comment: Added relevant code for buttons Tim, sorry for the inconvenience Tim i am new here

Comment: @acw1668, I am creating a button and when it is clicked then I am changing the configuration of the button instance, my issue here is the code is executing with my required format when i am running with spyder ide, but when i run the .py file, the format is changing, also attached the screenshots. Thanks for the suggestion i will implement what u said and ill check if it helps

Comment: @acw1668, thanks for the help. It is working normally after changing the font weight